# How to print blob type directly to jsp

Tags: jsp, blob

I'm making an app with jquerymobile + jsp

The structure is not like the normal servlet- jsp MVC.

It directly fetches the data and print it like this,

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>

<%! Connection con=null; %>
<%! Statement st= null; %>



<% 
try {
ResultSet rs= null; 
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/first_app";
String user = "root";
String password = "test"; 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
try {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM lunch_menu";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

%>


<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>MENU PAGE</h1>
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <!--
        <li><img src="/FirstApp/assets/img/1.jpg" />2013-10-08 똥맛카레</li>
        <li><img src="/FirstApp/assets/img/2.jpg" />2013-10-08 카레맛똥</li>
        -->
        <%

        while(rs.next()){
        Blob image = null;
        image = rs.getBlob("lunch_image");
        out.print("<li>");
            //prints com.mysql.jdbc.Blob@2d58497c
            out.print(rs.getBlob("lunch_image"));
            //prints [B@686fdca5
            //out.print(image.getBytes(1,(int)image.length()));


            out.print("</li>");
        }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){out.println(ce);}
        %>


        </ul>
    </div>


</div>
```

like i commented,

i've checked that the blob type data is existing, but i don't get it how to display the data. If this was jsp-servlet i know that i just have to do like this.

```
InputStream in = image.getBinaryStream();
int length = (int) image.length();
int bufferSize = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
out.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
```

but i don't get it like this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot print directly a blob type into an html (jsp) code. This will never work as you try to do it.

What I would suggest is to create a servlet that outputs images. See here how to do this [How to retrieve image from database and display in JSP via Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315671/how-to-retrieve-image-from-database-and-display-in-jsp-via-servlet) .And then in your code just call the servlet likeThis:

```
<img src='path_to_servlet/ServletName?imageId=xxx'>
```